# Add custom block to order view information in admin Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, view

I have overridden the core layout and template files using custom theme in **Magento 2**

And I have my block file at **Netenrich\Oms\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View**

template file at serge.beraud@alphanova.com.sg.Template has sample text

So I have `sales_order_view.xml` and i have added this code snippet at the end of `sales_order_view.xml`

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" name="sales_order_edit"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="left">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs" name="sales_order_tabs">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" name="order_tab_info" template="order/view/tab/info.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Messages" name="order_messages"/>
                <block class="Netenrich\Oms\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\View" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" name="order_info" template="order/view/info.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="order/view/items.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
                            <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
                            <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
                            <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                            <item name="ordered-qty" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                            <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Amount</item>
                            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Percent</item>
                            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Amount</item>
                            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row Total</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" template="order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
                            <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
                            <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price-original</item>
                            <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item>
                            <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item>
                            <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
                            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
                            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
                            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Qty" name="column_qty" template="items/column/qty.phtml" group="column"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="order_item_extra_info"/>
                </block>

                <container name="payment_additional_info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="order-payment-additional" />
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Payment" name="order_payment"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History" name="order_history" template="order/view/history.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="gift_options" template="Magento_Sales::order/giftoptions.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Giftmessage" name="order_giftmessage" template="order/view/giftmessage.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="order/totals.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals\Tax" name="tax" template="order/totals/tax.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_info</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">order_tab_info</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices" name="sales_order_invoice.grid.container"/>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_invoices</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_invoice.grid.container</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos" name="sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container"/>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_creditmemos</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Shipments" name="sales_order_shipment.grid.container"/>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_shipments</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_shipment.grid.container</argument>
            </action>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_history</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Transactions" name="sales_transactions.grid.container"/>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_transactions</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_transactions.grid.container</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="sales_page_head_components" template="Magento_Sales::page/js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="sales_order_invoice.grid.container">
        <uiComponent name="sales_order_view_invoice_grid"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container">
        <uiComponent name="sales_order_view_creditmemo_grid"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="sales_order_shipment.grid.container">
        <uiComponent name="sales_order_view_shipment_grid"/>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="order_info">
        <block class="Netenrich\Oms\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\View" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>


    <referenceContainer name="left">
       <referenceContainer name="payment_additional_info">
        <block class="Netenrich\Oms\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_ad" template="Magento_Sales:/order/view/custom.phtml"/>
         </referenceContainer>
    </referenceContainer>

</body>
```

**=> custom.php**

```
namespace Netenrich\Oms\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;
class View extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    //
}
```

> app/design/adminhtml/Netenrich/oms/Magento_Sales/templates/order/view/custom.phtml

```
<h>hi..hello</>
```

Comment: are you overriding or trying to inserting your custom new block?

Comment: NO..where we have to create di.xml for what purpose.

Comment: are you overriding or trying to inserting your custom new block?

Comment: i haved overridden the layout file already and trying to add new custom block to the overridden layout

Comment: post your full of code, so that we will update you where you went wrong?

Comment: i have posted full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55054/discussion-between-vijay-b-and-magento-two).

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: yeah..not completed yet..just 2 mins.i will post the results

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

**Learning/RewriteSales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Custom.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;
class Custom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{

}
```

**Learning/RewriteSales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceBlock name="order_additional_info">
            <block class="Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Learning/RewriteSales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/custom.phtml**

```
<h1>Hi, I am here!</h1>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/Netenrich/oms/Magento_Sales/templates/order/view/info.phtml‌​**

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('sales_order_view_custom') ?>
```

after completing this try to execute `setup:upgrade` and `setup:static-content:deploy` and Open any order.

Comment: change app/design/adminhtml/Netenrich/oms/Magento_Sales/templates/order/view/custom.phtml into app/design/adminhtml/Netenrich/oms/Magento_Sales/templates/order/view/info.phtml.

Comment: Yes I missed it.

Comment: how can we get the customer id in our Learning/RewriteSales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Custom.php.If we could get the order id or customer id in this custom.php .we can insert any data of respective customer dynamically

Comment: i got the answer .. extend the \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info in custom.php.-->class View extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info..So we can use the core methods from \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info which has the methods to get the order details

Comment: @vijayb do you want to answer how to get customer detail from `custom.php` or you got answer from somewhere?

Comment: Yeah..I want to get customer details but I got the answer..

Comment: Okay, go ahead..

Answer (score 3):

This would be much easier,
In `sales_order_view.xml`

```
 <referenceBlock name="order_additional_info">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" name="sales_order_custom_view" template="custom_view.phtml" />
 </referenceBlock>
```

Then create `custom_view.phtml` and place your custom code there.
Your code block will reflect before the Item section block in the admin order view interface.

In `info.phtml` in core file, already they allocated a section for additional custom blocks,

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('order_additional_info') ?>
```

Comment: Which folder should the custom_view.phtml be put in?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.3 onwards

sales_order_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="order_additional_info">
            <container name="basys_info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="basys_info">
                <block name="basysinfo.viewmodel" template="BA_BasysOrders::order/view/basysinfo.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">BA\BasysOrders\ViewModel\BasysInfo</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceBlock>
```

View Model Class

```
    <?php
namespace BA\BasysOrders\ViewModel;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class BasysInfo implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    protected $logger;
    protected $request;
    protected $order;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Http $request,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $order
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->order = $order;
    }
    public function getOrderId()
    {
        $this->logger->info('order id '.$this->request->getParam('order_id'));
        $order = $this->order->get(60);
        $this->logger->info('basys order id '.$order->getData('basys_order_id'));
        return $order->getData('basys_order_id');
    }
}
```

Phtml template

```
    <?php
    $viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
?>
<h3>Additional Information</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Order Id : <?= $block->escapeHtml($viewModel->getOrderId()); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Isn't this sample supposed to use getOrderId() differently?  What is the point of using a static `$this->order->get(60)` static value?  Isn't the dynamic `order_id` stored in the request?  `$this->request->getParam('order_id')`.  Was this just an oversight, otherwise how do we get/use the order id?