# Align Content in Order View Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, custom-theme

I added content using this [Instruction](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94066/add-content-to-order-view-magento-2)

It's Working fine! Content is coming! But i need my custom Content at last! I don't want my custom content in middle of something! How can i align that?? [image]

My sales_order_view.xml file is this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <block class="Backend\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Please post the layout xml you are using?

Comment: Wait! i will add

Comment: Do you want the custom content after everything on that page?

Comment: I need my custom content below Order  & Account Information section

Comment: If that's not possible after everything is also nice

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Backend\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Happy to help! Upvote please.